# Calling a java script function with php on click

Tags: php, javascript

Ok so i have paid a coder to code me a walk around map script were users can press up and down on the keyboard and walk aroud a map using jquery. But now im trying to make it so i have a up and down image and then on click it will call the up and down function. So the suer can use the up and down keys plus clicking the images.

Here is the up function im using for when the user presses the up key on the keyboard. But now some how i need to call the same function when a image is clicked..

```
function move(d)
{
    if(d == "UP")
    {
        var top = (parseInt(document.getElementById('move').style.top) - 10);
        var left = parseInt(document.getElementById('move').style.left);
        if(canMove(new xy(left,top)))
        {
            document.getElementById('move').style.top = (parseInt(document.getElementById('move').style.top) - 10) + 'px';
            document.player.src = "maps/sprites/playerUp.png";
            //if(lastStep != "UP") clearTimeouts();
            //setTimeout('document.player.src="playerUp.png"', 500);
            //lastStep = "UP";
            reloadF();
        }
    }
```

How would i do about doing that ??

Im guessing i just need to call function move(d) and set it to up some how ?? On click of image ?

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP or jQuery (seeing that you're not using jQuery). this is only javascript.

Comment: and if you ARE going to use jQuery, this would be simple as something like `$('.your-image').click(function() { move("UP"); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var keynum = 0;

if(window.event) { keynum = e.keyCode; }  // for IE
else if(e.which) { keynum = e.which; }    // for others browsers

if(keynum === 38) { // up
    //if KEY UP
}

if(keynum === 40) { // down
    //if KEY DOWN
}
```

I hope this help...

Comment: what im trying to say is i need it so when a html button or image is clicked it called the function above....

Comment: If you can't figure that out, it's time to hire another coder.